# Ebib: completion customization

Tags: emacs, bibtex

Ebib allows to customize the fields that can be completed (in Ebib itself). The manual says that I can customize the user option `ebib-edit-fields-functions`. But when I try to customize it, I get an error.

Here's the sequence. Run `emacs -Q` (Windows 10). `M-x ebib RET` Ebib panes appear, no bibtex buffer loaded. `M-x customize-option RET ebib-field-edit-functions RET`. In the lower third pane I see the usual emacs customization interface: "For help using this buffer, see Easy Customization in the Emacs manual. Operate on all settings in this buffer." But there are no settings to modify. In the minibuffer the message is: "Wrong type argument: listp, "Fields" "

What am I doing wrong? Total Lisp ignoramus here.

Comment: Show what you do and what you see, in a step-by-step recipe starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Move all such info that's relevant to the question, please. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable.

Comment: I suggest to submit bug report to [`ebib` repo](https://github.com/joostkremers/ebib) regarding [`:type`](https://github.com/joostkremers/ebib/blob/5a03e4662dccbffe63605bb8e88bfb691ebe0afa/ebib-utils.el#L1172C10-L1173C49).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of a bug in the line 1172 in `ebib-utils.el`. The correct code must read:

`:type '(repeat (cons (repeat :tag "Fields" (string))`

Pull request submitted on the Ebib [github page](https://github.com/joostkremers/ebib/pull/279).

Comment: a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add [context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).